# Replace previous and subsequent values of a column if a condition is met

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe and want to replace the values of column PHASE with "Before" for 7 rows before every incidence of "Day_1". Similarly, in the same column, I want to fill in "After" for 7 rows after the last day of Menstruation (Day_*, as the number of days for each menstrual cycle changes). Within this data set I need to group by SID and not overwrite any values already present in the column PHASE (Day_1-Day_*).

```
        dput(head(data, n = 35))
structure(list(UID = c("UAB001_W1D1", "UAB001_W1D2", "UAB001_W1D3", 
"UAB001_W1D4", "UAB001_W1D5", "UAB001_W1D6", "UAB001_W1D7", "UAB001_W2D1", 
"UAB001_W2D2", "UAB001_W2D3", "UAB001_W2D4", "UAB001_W2D5", "UAB001_W2D6", 
"UAB001_W2D7", "UAB001_W3D1", "UAB001_W3D2", "UAB001_W3D3", "UAB001_W3D4", 
"UAB001_W3D5", "UAB001_W3D6", "UAB001_W3D7", "UAB001_W4D1", "UAB001_W4D2", 
"UAB001_W4D3", "UAB001_W4D4", "UAB001_W4D5", "UAB001_W4D6", "UAB001_W4D7", 
"UAB001_W5D1", "UAB001_W5D2", "UAB001_W5D3", "UAB001_W5D4", "UAB001_W5D5", 
"UAB001_W5D6", "UAB001_W5D7"), SID = c("UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", 
"UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", 
"UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", 
"UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", 
"UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", 
"UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001", "UAB001"), SERIAL = c(" 1", " 2", 
" 3", " 4", " 5", " 6", " 7", " 8", " 9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35"
), WEEK = c(" 1", " 1", " 1", " 1", " 1", " 1", " 1", " 2", " 2", 
" 2", " 2", " 2", " 2", " 2", " 3", " 3", " 3", " 3", " 3", " 3", 
" 3", " 4", " 4", " 4", " 4", " 4", " 4", " 4", " 5", " 5", " 5", 
" 5", " 5", " 5", " 5"), DAY = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7"), NUGENT_SCORE = c(" 0", " 0", " 1", " 3", " 3", 
" 3", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 3", " 1", " 2", " 2", " 3", " 0", " 1", 
" 1", " 2", " 1", " 0", " 5", " 2", " 5", " 7", " 7", " 6", " 6", 
" 7", " 5", " 5", " 7", " 4", " 5", " 3", " 3"), NUGENT_CLASS = c("NO_BV", 
"NO_BV", "NO_BV", "NO_BV", "NO_BV", "NO_BV", "NO_BV", "NO_BV", 
"NO_BV", "NO_BV", "NO_BV", "NO_BV", "NO_BV", "NO_BV", "NO_BV", 
"NO_BV", "NO_BV", "NO_BV", "NO_BV", "NO_BV", "INTER_BV", "NO_BV", 
"INTER_BV", "BV", "BV", "INTER_BV", "INTER_BV", "BV", "INTER_BV", 
"INTER_BV", "BV", "INTER_BV", "INTER_BV", "NO_BV", "NO_BV"), 
    CST = c("I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
    "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "III", 
    "I", "IV-C", "III", "IV-B", "III", "III", "IV-B", NA, "I", 
    NA, "IV-C", "I", "IV-C", "IV-C"), PH = c("4.4", "4.0", "4.0", 
    "4.4", "4.4", "4.7", "4.4", "4.0", "4.0", "4.4", "4.0", "4.0", 
    "4.0", "4.4", "4.4", "5.3", "5.3", "5.3", "5.0", "4.7", "5.3", 
    "4.4", "4.0", "4.4", "4.7", "4.7", "4.7", "4.4", "5.8", "5.5", 
    "4.7", "4.7", "4.7", "4.7", "4.7"), MENSTRUATION = c("0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "2", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0"), TAMPON = c(" 0", 
    " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", 
    " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", 
    " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", 
    " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0"), PAD = c(" 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", 
    " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", 
    " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", 
    " 0", " 0", " 0", " 0", " 1", " 1", " 1", " 1", " 0", " 0", 
    " 0"), Hygiene_Product = c("None", "None", "None", "None", 
    "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", 
    "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", 
    "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", 
    "Pad", "Pad", "Pad", "Pad", "None", "None", "None"), MENSES = c("NO", 
    "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", 
    "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", 
    "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "YES", "YES", "YES", 
    "YES", "NO", "NO", "NO"), MEN.DAY = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0), MEN.CYCLE.DAY = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
    17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), PHASE = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Day_1", "Day_2", "Day_3", 
    "Day_4", NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -35L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have tried the following, but it replaced some Days with "Before", both between different SIDs and within SIDs.

```
datat$PHASE[pmin(nrow(data), unique(unlist(lapply(which(data$PHASE == "Day_1"), `-`, 1:7))))] <- "Before"
```

I also tried putting the above into a for loop to create new dataframes for each SID that I could then cat together as I already have a list of SIDs (patients), but it doesn't work for SIDs with Day_1 within the first 6 rows or the final Day less than 6 days from the end of the dataframe.

```
for (i in patients) {
  tryCatch({
    data.filt <- data %>% 
                          filter(SID == i) 
    data.filt$PHASE[pmin(nrow(data.filt), unique(unlist(lapply(which(data.filt$PHASE == "Day_1"), `-`, 1:7))))] <- "Before"
    assign(paste0(i), data.filt)
  }, error = function(e){cat(paste0(i, "_ERROR :", conditionMessage(e), "\n"))})
}
```

If someone could please help me fill in this data accurately, I would greatly appreciate it!

*** Answer from Ben worked perfectly:

```
data <- data %>%
                group_by(SID) %>%
                mutate(Start = if_else(is.na(lag(PHASE)) & grepl("Day_", PHASE), row_number(), NA),
                       End = if_else(is.na(lead(PHASE)) & grepl("Day_", PHASE), row_number(), NA)) %>%
                fill(Start, .direction = "up") %>%
                fill(End, .direction = "down") %>%
                mutate(PHASE = if_else(is.na(PHASE) & (Start - row_number() <= 7), "Before", PHASE)) %>%
                mutate(PHASE = if_else(is.na(PHASE) & (row_number() - End <= 7), "After", PHASE))
```

Comment: For questions asking for help on code please provide a sample of the data not in a picture. You can use `dput(head(data))` to share the first few lines.

Comment: @AWillz In addition to above, can a single person `SID` have multiple mentrual cycles in the data? Or will there only be one cycle per person?

Comment: @Ben Yes, each SID has at least 2 cycles and some are within 7 days of each other because the data includes people on new birth control and others going through premenopause, so even grouping by SID caused some menstrual days to be overwritten.

Comment: @AWillz If two cycles are within 7 days of each other, how do you want them labelled - which are "after" the first, and which are "before" the second, if there's overlap?

Comment: @Ben that is a good question from a research point of view! It should probably be "after".

Comment: @AWillz Thanks - see answer below and let me know if this is what you had in mind; hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to keep track in two columns the start and end of each phase (which can be stored as `row_number()`) or you can use a separate counter (like `Serial` in the data if it's numeric). You can detect when a phase starts/ends by looking if preceding or following row is missing (before or after a phase). Then, you can use `fill` for other rows to have this available to reference, based on closest phase in the dataset. The label of "Before" and "After" are added when the difference between the current row position and the start/end value is <= 7. All of this will be done grouped by `SID`.

**Note**: you can reverse the statements for "Before" and "After" depending on which would get priority if there is overlap.

```
library(tidyverse)

datat |>
  group_by(SID) |>
  mutate(Start = if_else(is.na(lag(PHASE)) & grepl("Day_", PHASE), row_number(), NA),
         End = if_else(is.na(lead(PHASE)) & grepl("Day_", PHASE), row_number(), NA)) |>
  fill(Start, .direction = "up") |>
  fill(End, .direction = "down") |>
  mutate(PHASE = if_else(is.na(PHASE) & (Start - row_number() <= 7), "Before", PHASE)) |>
  mutate(PHASE = if_else(is.na(PHASE) & (row_number() - End <= 7), "After", PHASE))
```